# Possible to '--eval' with javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

is it possible to call Node.js interpreter to evaluate a javascript file instead of script string on the CMD with the '--eval' parameter? I am using a Windows machine for development, but I hope what CMD envirement shouldn't really matter much.

What I am trying to achieve is combine two separate javascript files, so that the code (class, object, method, functions) in the first javascript file can be shared with code in the second javascript file, as if they are in a single file.

I know it's sounds like I should be using module. But my problem is not exactly 'how to design my code base so that I can have separate JS files'. So if you want to know way, please bear with me: I have a few small projects, the code were written by someone else which often is using modules internal already, but not exposed as library. But I want extent its functions. The code works fine for it's purpose so there is normally no need for me modified those code at all. So what's happens often is I only need write a few lines of code based on the existing code, reusing the majority of the code, which might already doing `require` already. And once I have a working solution, I start over, trying different approach, which may or may not end up as a working solution. So I potentially have a few new files in the projects.

The main things is that I want separate my code from the existing code. I think the sensible ways to do it is just code the existing code I need and import the modules I need into my code again. Or if I insist, redesign the existing code to be modules so I can easily import the function to my need. But I think I like the idea of separating my code, but do not expose existing code to a library which might be end up need be res-structured as well. So yes, I don't think modules is answer for all the situations.

To achieve what I wan I think the best solution is possible using `--eval` in Node.js to load the code in the first javascript file. But I just can't get it working. The alternative is `eval(require("fs").readFileSync(".\\Code\\baseCode.js", "utf8"));`, but I think the `--eval` in CMD is slightly better as I can then put the full path js file into a launch file in VS code.

**Update**

**Latest update**, it occurred to me that Windows CMD might broken or NodeJs not working that well with Windows CMD, so I tried integrated terminal in VS Code and `node --eval "$(cat first.js second.js)` works as expected.

Solution I tried in Windows CMD but doesn't working

```
D:\Test\JSNodeJSEval>node --eval "$(cat first.js second.js)"
[eval]:1
$(cat first.js second.js)
  ^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:466:27)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

D:\Test\JSNodeJSEval>node --eval "$(< first.js second.js)"
[eval]:1
$(< first.js second.js)
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:466:27)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: It sounds like what you're really trying to do is to avoid node.js modules.  IMO, that is a mistake.  Modules are your friend.  They make code more testable, more shareable and force you to think through a number of good design steps when designing it.  Stop avoiding modules.  Learn them.  Go with them.  Any effort you put into to trying to avoid them will be better applied to learning them and using them.  It takes a little getting used to that there's extra boilerplate-type code at the start of each module to "import" what you need from other modules, but it's worth it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think you have a good point, in term of design, module solution is almost always better. but I am asking the question because I feel the `--eval` should be a working solution, but I just can't seems get it working.

Comment: Should be a working solution for what problem?  For the problem of how to avoid using modules?  That's my point.  If you just use modules like it sounds like you know you probably should, then you don't have to solve this other problem.

Comment: Ok @jfriend00, I think I own you an explanation, please see my updated question: I am trying to reusing existing code, and most of them is using modules already. But I don't see the need to expose those code base for what I am trying to achieve. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted to you could just output the two files in order and evaluate the string. Example:

```
echo 'var a = 1;' > first.js
echo 'console.log(a);' > second.js

node --eval "$(cat first.js second.js)"
1
```

Of course, programming with implicit global variables is something we try not to do, especially when `import a from './first.js';`  is so easy to write and has more benefits.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I added details that I am asking for a Windows environment, hence the `CMD` tag, so `cat` wouldn't be available, but I think I should be able to use pipe `<` or `|` for pipe?

Comment: Tried with `<`, does't work, see error message from my update. not sure how pipes working for Windows,